# Powershell script to find out expiry date for listed computers

Tags: powershell

I have list of computers which are issued with client auth certificate, I am trying to find out the expiry date for the listed computers and all of them are issued from a common template.  when I tried to use

```
certutil -view -restrict "CertificateTemplate=<oid>, Disposition==20" -out "Issued Common Name,RequestID,Certificate Expiration Date"
```

I am able to get the expiry details for all the certs issued from the template however I just want to find out the expiry date for listed common name.  For loop is not yielding any results. could you please help

```
$servers=D:\servers.txt
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
  certutil -view -restrict "Issued Common Name,RequestID,Certifcate Expiration Date"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as familiar with the certutil command but you will need a way to tell that command to look at the PC's you're looping through. Right now you have a loop that just loops through a list of PCs but doesn't do anything with them. Look up the certutil syntax and see if theres a parameter that lets you specify a particular computer. For example, (this is not the right syntax but the logic on how I think it would be done):

```
$servers=D:\servers.txt
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
  certutil -view -restrict -computer $server "Issued Common Name,RequestID,Certifcate Expiration Date"
}
```